# Does the ampersand need to be escaped?

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping

I am attempting to create a function in python 2.7.8 to delete files that are no longer needed on a remote PC.

If I run it from the command line I am able to do this:

```
C:\>del /f /q \\RemotePC\d$\temp\testfile.txt && if exist \\RemotePC\d$\temp\testfile.txt (set errorlevel=1) else (set errorlevel=0)
```

From this I get the expected result:

```
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

But when I attempt to put this into my python function it does not work. The test variable does not get set.

Here is what I have in my python function:

```
def DelFile(self, address, del_file):
    cmd_line = "del /f /q \\\\" + address + del_file + "\&\& if exist \"\\\\" + address + del_file + "\" (set errorlevel=1) else (set errorlevel=0)"

    myP = subprocess.Popen(cmd_line, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    out = timeout(myP.communicate, (), {}, 120, (None, None))
    result = out[0]
    error = out[1]
    error_code = None
    error_code = myP.returncode
    notes = []

    return cmd_line, result, error, error_code, notes
```

I have verified that the `address` and `del_file` variables are formatted correctly in order to get me to the desired file. I have also verified that it deletes or does not delete the intended file based on the circumstances. But for some reason the test variable never gets set.

It is my understanding that the ampersand character needs to be escaped, like so `"\&"` when being used in a string. Is this not true or am I not escaping it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, turns out I actually had a few. The first being that the ampersand apparently does not need to be escaped (Thank you FirebladeDan), the second being that I was missing a space before the ampersands (Thank you again to FirebladeDan for the tip with formatting, that is how I noticed the missing space). The last being more of a CMD issue than python, I was trying to directly set the `errorlevel` variable, when I should have been using the `exit /b` with the respective `1` or `0`.

As a side note, I also added in the use of `psexec`, it was not necessary for the solution, it just helps with the performance of the overall program.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
def DelFile(self, address, del_file):
    cmd_line = r'psexec \\{0} cmd /c "del /f /q "{1}" && if exist "{1}" (exit /b 1) else (exit /b 0)"'.format(address, del_file)

    myP = subprocess.Popen(cmd_line, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    out = timeout(myP.communicate, (), {}, 60, (None, None))
    result = out[0]
    error = out[1]
    error_code = None
    error_code = myP.returncode
    notes = []

    return cmd_line, result, error, error_code, notes
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cmd_line should look like this

```
cmd_line = "del /f /q \\\\{0}{1} & if exist \\\\{0}{1} (set test=1) else (set test=0)".format(address, del_file)
```

Try using one &

Comment: Sorry, I had accidentally posted the snippet of my test code, I edited by post and updated it to my original code. Really the only difference is that I do not have a variable named test, I am trying to set the variable errorlevel. Also, I have tried a single ampersand and I was still unable to get it to work.